# Are JScrambler services safe for protecting javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I recently stumbled upon **jscrambler.com**
This tool actually allows you to protect your javascript code, its fascinating. However, the service is cloud based and im wondering if this is really ok. Since im actually posting code on their servers. While others cant steal my code, it is still vurnerable to theft from within the the guys behind jscrambler.

Maybe im worrying too much. Is it safe to use jscrambler services?

Comment: Seriously, if you downvote at least explain why lol.

Comment: Your JavaScript code will still have to run in my browser at some point.  I don't know how their system works, but my developer tools/debugger may still show me your code.

Comment: You cannot fully protect Javascript code.  Any code that a user can run can also be disassembled.  All you can do is make it harder.

Comment: @RocketHazmat they apparently have anti debugging tools or something

Comment: This isn't a coding question. It's asking about whether a service may be vulnerable.

Comment: Why is your code special?

Comment: @SLaks they have tools that prevent reverse engineering. Not sure how it works

Comment: If the JS ever runs in my browser, I certainly can read and reverse engineer it. It may be harder, but they can't make it impossible to reverse engineer it.

Comment: @Reeno how come so many big companies use it? For example bandai and samsung. Or maybe its a lie, maybe they just used it once for a little project and are now featured in their list. If thats true what all of you are saying then these companies cant possibly take it too seriously

Comment: @Asperger It depends on the goal of these companies. If they just want to make it harder to read their JS code, they surely can use services like this. If they really think this service makes it impossible to read the JS code, they need some real consulting :)

Comment: @Reeno its ironic though how those companies post their naked code to a 3rd party to encrypt the files.

Comment: @Asperger Jscrambler has an on-premises solution (Virtual Machine) for those who can't/won't send their code to a 3rd party on the Web [link](https://jscrambler.com/en/box).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. Giving your code to a 3rd party to protect it is as counter-productive as it is counter-intuitive.

That said, browser users **always have access to the underlying Javascript code**. The most you can do is wrangle the source code by making syntactic changes that produce the same functionality but result in harder-to-read text.

This process is known as *uglification* or *minification* (since it reduces file size). [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) is the most frequently used tool for this.

Comment: Apparently they have some technique that makes the app fail when the user does some tampering and reverse engineering. What also made me curious is that they can bind the app with certain domains and make it expire. Namco, Samsung etc use it too. A lot of big guys but im honestly really scared due to them being 3rd party. They can change their terms of use without notice

Comment: What are you trying to protect yourself from? If it's code theft, uglification is the only way to protect the source (and the industry standard). If you're trying to protect your users from hackers, I would tackle that problem as separate. If you're trying to protect your servers from malicious requests, the security defects are in your servers, not your clients -- client code is unsafe by definition, servers should be able to protect themselves.

Comment: Actually I have writte 50.000 lines of code. Its a project I created for my studies and I really want to protect it. Usually I keep things open source but this one I really want to protect. I mean just so the average developer cant just steal it. I dont mind about the big guys, it would be an honor there : ) . But I think you know what I mean. So things like uglifyJs are find for the task? of course if someone really wants to take the time and encode it then its always possible, im aware.

Comment: If you want to guard the code from other developer's eyes, `uglifyJS` is the way to go. Use it and take a look at the results, I trust you will be satisfied

Comment: Thanks, accepted the answer. Sorry if its not a pure coding question. I usually dont ask such type of questions here. Thanks!

Comment: @slezica uglifyJS is not meant to protect anything. It is considered a code optimization tool, where a slight obfuscation is nothing but a side-effect. It's rather trivial to reverse uglifyjs code.